# Unexpected non-void return value in void function(swift4.0.3)

Tags: ios

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Login"
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    //Mark:- making UITextFeild

    let UserName: UITextField
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.borderStyle = .none
    tf.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    tf.backgroundColor = UIColor()
    tf.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.5)
    tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    tf.autocorrectionType = .no

    //Mark:- PlaceHolder

    var placeholder = NSMutableAttributedString()
    placeholder = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString(string: "UserName", attributes: [.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)]))
   tf.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder
    return tf
    //This Error:-Unexpected non-void return value in void function after when I return tf
}
```

Comment: write a function that return UITextField(), and put your code their,  and it will work!

Comment: Why do you do `return tf`? You are in method `viewDidLoad()`, so why are you returning the textField? What's the purpose of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it you are trying to define `UserName` using tf as a calculated variable which should be done in a block like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Login"
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    //Mark:- making UITextFeild

    var UserName: UITextField {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.borderStyle = .none
        tf.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor()
        tf.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.5)
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        tf.autocorrectionType = .no

        //Mark:- PlaceHolder

        var placeholder = NSMutableAttributedString()
        placeholder = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString(string: "UserName", attributes: [.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)]))
        tf.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder
        return tf
    }
}
```

Note the extra set of braces.

Also UserName needs to become var because you can't use a computed type for a let variable.

Also worth mentioning that UserName will be completely local to the viewDidLoad method and not added to the view hierarchy but that might be just because there is more code not shown or not yet added.